# TestCafe / Multiple repository project

Tags: javascript, user-interface, testing, babeljs, testcafe

I have my TestCafe page models grouped together in different project repositories.

When I try to use these page model repositories/packages in the main project that has the tests, I get various different errors. The latest error I get when I try to run a test that makes use of a page model in a different package is this:

```
Cannot implicitly resolve the test run in the context of which the test controller action should be executed. Use test function's 't' argument instead.
```

My page model repository uses babel and has the following in the babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": {
                    "node": true
                },
                "modules": "commonjs",
                "forceAllTransforms": true,
                "debug": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

If I don't use babel on the page model repositories, I get issues related to unknown import tokens.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import ...
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Can someone give me advice on how to get a multiple repository TestCafe project working?

Answer (score 3):

I fear this is not possible, because all test code and all imports must be transpiled by TestCafe before executing tests.
Because of this, TestCafe will also ignore any `babelrc` you might setup. All TestCafe code and all page models should be in the same repository.

Comment: Indeed, @hdorgeval is correct.

As a workaround, you might want to take a look at some custom module loader. For example, I check out the `esm` module:

[https://github.com/standard-things/esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm)
[https://medium.com/web-on-the-edge/tomorrows-es-modules-today-c53d29ac448c](https://medium.com/web-on-the-edge/tomorrows-es-modules-today-c53d29ac448c)